# DependencyProperty default value in Visual Studio designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, dependency-properties

How do I provide a default value to a binding in a UserControl's XAML, in such a way that Visual Studio will correctly pick up on it?

I'm trying to implement a reusable WPF UserControl, which uses DependencyProperties to customize its behavior, and I'm running into strange behavior in Visual Studio regarding the property's default value.

Take the following control:

Widget.designer.cs

```
namespace WpfPropertiesTest
{
    public partial class Widget : UserControl
    {
        public Widget()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Test), typeof(string), typeof(Widget),
                new PropertyMetadata("Hello World"));

        public string Test
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Widget.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfPropertiesTest.Widget"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         x:Name="_this">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Test, FallbackValue='Fallback', TargetNullValue='Null', Mode=OneWay}" />
</UserControl>
```

When I look at the designer of Widget.xaml, I see the fallback value, which is reasonable:

[image: Visual Studio WPF designer shows 'Fallback value'.]

However, lets say I now add a Widget to a window:

```
// TestWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfPropertiesTest.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfPropertiesTest"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="100" Width="200">
   <Grid>
       <local:Widget />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would expect to see one of either "Hello World", "Fallback", or "Null", but what I actually get is this:

[image: Visual Studio designer now shows 'Test' in the window.]

... Which is the name of the property that I'm binding to.

At runtime, using the same code, I can see the default value just fine:

[image: Window shows 'Hello World' at runtime.]

Now, if I explicitly set a value for the property:

```
<local:Widget Test="A value that I put in." />
```

The designer now correctly shows:

[image: Visual Studio designer now shows 'A value that I put in.']

All of this tells me that my binding is correct, but the Visual Studio (reasonably) doesn't actually look at the dependency properties in the codebehind. This becomes a problem when I'm actually doing something with the property, such as binding visibility to it.

So, what am I missing? Is there some way to give Visual Studio a value to use in the designer? I don't want to have to explicitly set all of my UserControl properties every time I use it, and I would like to have the control behave in the designer as close to runtime as possible.

Should I forego the binding altogether, and just set the value in the codebehind in the property callback?

In a more general sense, is this the correct approach for making reusable UserControls that can be configured by the consumer?

Comment: `Path=ChildText`? Was that just an omission in translating the real code to the example?

Comment: In VS2017, in the designer, what I see for `<local:Widget />` is "Fallback". At runtime I see "Hello World".

Comment: @EdPlunkett, yes, sorry, that was an omission.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I don't know why we get different results. I am on Visual Studio 2017 version 15.4.0.

Comment: May just be a designer issue. Did you try clean build and restart VS?

Comment: More or less as Ed, I see "Fallback" in the control designer, "Hello World" in window designer and runtime (VS 2017 version 15.2 Community Edition)

Comment: I've created a new solution, with a new WPF project, and lo and behold, I'm getting 'Fallback' as well now. I still have it consistently showing 'Test' in my main project however, and I have no idea how to begin debugging that...

Comment: Even stranger, now I'm actually getting "Hello World" in the designer, in my empty WPF test project! I'm baffled.

Comment: So, if I clean my solution, and open the designer immediately after, without compiling, I get 'Fallback'. But as soon as I build the project, I start getting 'Test'. Is there anything in my project that could be overriding the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

If I'm not mistaken the reason for that behavior is that you have project code disabled in your designer. To enable project code toggle the rightmost button in the bottom part of the designer, right to the left from the scroll bar.

## Diagnosis

Let's do a simple experiment. Firstly, let's create simple test class:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class EmptyClass { }
}
```

Then let's put this *XAML* code in some *XAML* control with a designer:

```
<Grid xmlns:test="clr-namespace:Test">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Provider"
                            ObjectType="test:EmptyClass"
                            MethodName="GetType" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Provider}}" />
</Grid>
```

Now in the designer view, when project code is enabled, we see `Test.EmptyClass`. However, when project code is disabled, we see something along the lines of `Mocks.Test_EmptyClass_0_96752088`. This leads to a conclusion that the designer uses a generated mock class rather than the actual class (which is what I'd expect - that the designer is not using code from my project).

I don't know the exact mechanics of generating mock classes. Perhaps the static constructor for the mocked class is not called, or the mock class does not even derive from the original class. Either way, your code, which assigns the default property metadata, is not (and should not be) executed.